# ui.grid using $scope at gridApi face error on $scope not define

Tags: angular-ui-grid

face issue of $scope not define, any help

```
    this.gridOptions3 = {

        data: this.pnasgn,
        // enableCellEditOnFocus: false,
        // enableRowSelection: false,
        enableColumnResizing: true,
        enableFiltering: false,
        enableGridMenu: false,
        showGridFooter: true,
        showColumnFooter: true,
        fastWatch: true,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
        // rowIdentity: getRowId,
        // getRowIdentity: getRowId,
        importerDataAddCallback: (grid, newObjects)=> {
            this.pnasgn = this.pnasgn.concat(newObjects);
        },
        columnDefs: [
            {
                field: 'PNASGN',
                displayName: 'Part Number Assigned',

            },
            {
                field: 'QITNUM',
                displayName: 'QIT Number',

            }
        ],
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){$scope.gridApi3 = gridApi}

    };
```

1st time user of ui-grid, trying to refresh the html ui-grid when there is change in gridOptions.data

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question. Consider rewriting the question properly.

Comment: Fix code formatting